# Authenticate User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to asp.net and C# and I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC web application where I have to manage user login and different rights in the app.

So what I have done so far: I have a model class for my user model:

```
public class UserModel 
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Prompt = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Display(Prompt = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Int32 GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public Boolean GroupAccess { get; set; }

    // CheckUserPassword
}
```

In my view I use 2 `<input>` controls to gather the username and password. I have a function in my model to check the username/password:

```
public int CheckUserPassword() 
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(GetConString.ConString());
    string query = "select PASSWORD from USERS where USERNAME='" + Username + "'"; 

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    string upass = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    con.Close();

    int i = 0;

    if (Password == upass)
        i = 1;

    return i;
}
```

And in my controller I call the function `CheckUserPassword()`; if the user exists, I `return View("Index")`, else I do `return View("Error")`.

After the user is redirected to Index, he gets a view with his access rights. 3-4 others views and controllers.

Since, I'm using a pre-seeded Oracle database I haven't found any way to use something similar like Entity Framework.

My question is, how can I check if the user is authenticated and how to store his username for future reference from other parts of my app?

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my bad English or lack of information.

Comment: You would probably want to take a look at ASP.NET Identity.  [ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

Comment: Don't create your own identity solution, it's a lot of work and very easy to make a small mistake which leaves your application vulnerable. You've already made at least one in your code above (by not parameterising your query). Leave it to the experts and use the ASP.NET Identity framework provided to you for free by Microsoft.